# Java - Access Modifiers - inheritance of public methods outside package

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, encapsulation

I'm a beginner in java.

I understand the public method is globally accessed. In the access modifiers tabular matrix, it was given as below

```
            Within Class  Within Package  outside Package     outside package
                                            by sub-class         class              
protected     Y                Y               Y                    N

public        Y                Y               Y                    Y
```

Now my query is on public access related to outside package class.

Assume public Class 1 having public methods is in package 1 and class 2 in package 2.

If I have to access Class 1 methods from Class2 then have to use “extends” keyword(to the best of my knowledge)

So on using “extends”, the class 2 becomes sub-class which ideally means am accessing Class1 from a subclass of different package which matches criteria “outside package by sub-class”

So then how condition "outside package by subclass" and "outside package class" are different?

You can refer the attached syntax where i am accessing public & protected method of different package. please clarify

```
package second; // different package

public class SubClass extends abnpackage.Play {// abnpackage is another package and Class Play having public & protected
    //methods - prot & pub.

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SubClass SC = new SubClass();
        SC.prot(); // protected method is shown
        SC.pub(); // public method is shown

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you say “then have to use ‘extends’ keyword” to access a method of a class? Is that what you do? What about `"something".length()`? Do I have to use `extends String` in that code example to access the `public` method `length()` declared in `java.lang.String`?

Comment: Please update on your progress

Comment: @ alex, thanks friend, for you clarification. have understood the logic and can proceed further.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the right answers so others can see that your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

> So then how condition "outside package by subclass" and "outside
>   package class" are different?

The first condition means, if the class is outisde the the package and not inheriting from target class, it cannot call `protected` members. It should extend target class for calling `protected` members from it's own instance.

The second case allows to call `public` methods always. No matter if inheritance exist or not.

Example:

```
package com.example

public class Super {

    public void pub() {   
    }

    protected void prot() {
    }
}
```

Child class:

```
package com.other

public class Sub extends Super {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sub sub = new Sub();
        sub.pub(); // this is legitimate call 
        sub.prot(); // this is legitimate call 

        Super su = new Super();
        su.pub(); // this is legitimate call 
        su.prot(); // this one will not compile because it's not visible
    } 
}
```

Not a child:

```
package com.other

public class Other {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Super su = Super();
        su.pub(); // this is legitimate call 
        su.prot(); // this one will not compile 
    } 
}
```

Moving other classes to the `com.example` package (where `Super` is placed):

Child class:

```
package com.example

public class Sub extends Super {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sub sub = new Sub();
        sub.pub(); // this is legitimate call 
        sub.prot(); // this is legitimate call 

        Super su = new Super();
        su.pub(); // this is legitimate call 
        su.prot(); // this is legitimate call now
    } 
}
```

Not a child:

```
package com.example

public class Other {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Super s = Super();
        s.pub(); // this is legitimate call 
        s.prot(); // this is legitimate call now 
    } 
}
```

General conclusion from example above:

- If the classes are in the same package, you can create instance of the target class (`Super` in this case) and call the `public/protected/package-private` members of the class from the created instance.
- If the classes in the different packages, you can create instance of the target class and call only `public` members from this instance. But if you are inheriting from target class, the descendant (`Sub`) can call protected methods, but only from the instance of `Sub`. You still have no chanse to call protected method from instance of target class.

Comment: hi friend, thanks for your quick reply.so what is the syntax for the public method which is accessed by a class of different package ?may be you can use my syntax as well?

Comment: @badri I extended the answer